# Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-messages failed with 410

Tags: bower

I am getting this error suddenly today.

> Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-messages failed with 410

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got this error just today.
https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2484 may shed some light on this.